# Are there any shortcuts to adjust the volume on ubuntu 20.04? My keyboard or headphones do not have dedicated media buttons on them?

Tags: sound, keyboard, shortcut-keys

My old keyboard had dedicated buttons for adjusting the volume, but my new keyboard does not. Is there a way to change the volume that is faster than clicking the speaker icon and then dragging it to the selected volume? I would prefer not to have to change windows to do this as well, as I often want to do this when watching a fullscreen video.

Answer (score 3):

you can add your own keyboard shortcut from settings

For this :

1. Go to settings.
2. Go to "Keyboard Shortcuts"
3. in search bar of "Keyboard Shortcuts" search using this keyword : "volume"
4. You will see three options : Volume Down , Volume Mute/Unmute , Volume Up
5. click on any option
6. set your own keyboard shortcut
7. Click "Set"
8. Now you can use that shorcut to control your volume

Answer (score 0):

You can manually configure keyboard shortcuts for various functions in Ubuntu. If you follow the steps at the top of [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en), it will bring you to the menu from which you can set a key binding for volume up and volume down (they should be pre-created items you just need to set the shortcut for). **ctrl+↑** and **ctrl+↓** may work well.

Steps from link:
**Open the Activities overview and start typing Settings.

Click on Settings.

Click Devices in the sidebar.

Click Keyboard in the sidebar to open the panel.

Click the row for the desired action. The Set shortcut window will be shown.

Hold down the desired key combination, or press Backspace to reset, or press Esc to  cancel.**